# Using MySQL Index Scans for Sorts

Tags: mysql, sorting, indexing

I study MySQL Index details by "High Performance MySQL" book and I can not understand one thing.

As book says, (p.124 Using Index Scans for Sorts)

> MySQL has two ways to produce ordered results: it can use a filesort,
>   or it can scan an index in order.
>
> Ordering the results by the index works only when the index’s order is
>   exactly the same as the ORDER BY clause and all columns are sorted in
>   the same direction (ascending or descending).
>
> The ORDER BY clause also has the same limitation as lookup queries: it
>   needs to form a leftmost prefix of the index. In all other cases,
>   MySQL uses a filesort.

further, authors give some examples using MySQL Sakila's example DataBase
[[http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/][1]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/%5d%5b1%5d)

First example works fine:

the rental table in the standard Sakila sample database has an index on
(rental_date, inventory_id, customer_id):

```
CREATE TABLE rental (
...
PRIMARY KEY (rental_id),
UNIQUE KEY rental_date (rental_date,inventory_id,customer_id),
KEY idx_fk_inventory_id (inventory_id),
KEY idx_fk_customer_id (customer_id),
KEY idx_fk_staff_id (staff_id),
...
);
```

> MySQL uses the rental_date index to order the following query, as you
>   can see from the lack of a filesort in EXPLAIN:

```
> mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT
> rental_id, staff_id FROM sakila.rental
> -> WHERE rental_date = '2005-05-25'
> -> ORDER BY inventory_id, customer_id\G
> *************************** 1. row *************************** 
> type: ref 
> possible_keys: rental_date 
> key: rental_date 
> rows: 1 
> Extra: Using where
```

> This works, even though the ORDER BY clause isn’t itself a
>   leftmost prefix of the index, because we specified an equality
>   condition for the first column in the index.

It is important to notice: they use index columns in where clause, but use different columns in SELECT query.

The second example are shown in short manner:

> The following query also works, because the two columns in the ORDER BY
>   are a left-most prefix of the index:
>
> ... WHERE rental_date > '2005-05-25' ORDER BY rental_date, inventory_id;

But here you can get different result rather your SELECT columns content:

First situation, filesort is used:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT `rental_id`, `staff_id` FROM `sakila`.`rental`
WHERE `rental_date` > '2005-05-25'
ORDER BY `rental_date`, `inventory_id`;
```

type: ALL 
possible_key: rental_date
key: NULL
Extra: Using where; using filesort

Second situation, index is used:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT `rental_id`, `rental_date`, `inventory_id` FROM `sakila`.`rental`
WHERE `rental_date` > '2005-05-25'
ORDER BY `rental_date`, `inventory_id`;
```

type: range
possible_key: rental_date
key: rental_date
Extra: Using where; Using index

Why does it work in this strange manner? As shown before, the first example used index sorting even if in SELECT clause was included different columns with WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

In the second query:

```
SELECT `rental_id`, `rental_date`, `inventory_id` FROM `sakila`.`rental`
WHERE `rental_date` > '2005-05-25'
ORDER BY `rental_date`, `inventory_id`;
```

MySql retrieves data directly from the index, and does not refer to the table at all.
Please take a look at the index definition and compare it with columns referenced by the query:

```
UNIQUE KEY rental_date (rental_date,inventory_id,customer_id)
```

The index contains all colums referenced by the query except `rental_id`, however `rental_id` is the primary key, and each index besides columns given explicitely in it's definition, always contains also primary key values.
This is a **covering index** for this query, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29#Covering_index

---

However in the first query:

```
SELECT `rental_id`, `staff_id` FROM `sakila`.`rental`
WHERE `rental_date` > '2005-05-25'
ORDER BY `rental_date`, `inventory_id`;
```

there is `staff_id` column, that is not stored in the index.
In this case MySql must first retrieve index entries that match WHERE condition, then for each entry must get the whole record from the table to obtain missing `staff_id` value for that entry.

---

Now please run this query against your database and examine it's results:

```
select count(*) As total,
           sum( case when `rental_date` > '2005-05-25' then 1 else 0 end ) As x1,
           sum( case when `rental_date` = '2005-05-25' then 1 else 0 end ) As x0
from rental
;
```

In my copy of `sakila database` this query has returned the following:

```
+ ---------- + ------- + ------- +
| total      | x1      | x0      |
+ ---------- + ------- + ------- +
| 16044      | 16036   | 0       |
+ ---------- + ------- + ------- +
```

As you see, almost all records in the table - 99,9% - are greater than `2005-05-25`.
In this case MySql decided to not use the index to retrieve rows from the table, but prefers to load the whole contents of the table into memory, and sort it here - the table is relatively small, contains only 16k records.
However if you revert the condition, MySql prefers the index acces method:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT `rental_id`, `staff_id` FROM `sakila`.`rental`
WHERE `rental_date` < '2005-05-25'
ORDER BY `rental_date`, `inventory_id`;
+ ------- + ---------------- + ---------- + --------- + ------------------ + -------- + ------------ + -------- + --------- + ---------- +
| id      | select_type      | table      | type      | possible_keys      | key      | key_len      | ref      | rows      | Extra      |
+ ------- + ---------------- + ---------- + --------- + ------------------ + -------- + ------------ + -------- + --------- + ---------- +
| 1       | SIMPLE           | rental     | range     | rental_date        | rental_date | 5            |          | 8         | Using index condition |
+ ------- + ---------------- + ---------- + --------- + ------------------ + -------- + ------------ + -------- + --------- + ---------- +
```

Why it doesn't use the index in the first case ? Because retrieving records from the table using the index entries is usually the most expensive method - really :)
The index is good only in cases where a very small portion of the table must be retrieved - a few percent, maybe < 10%. For each index record retrieved from the index, MySql must get one record using it's primary key - this is a random table access, which is a several times slower than sequential acess. 
To get only one record from the table by `id`, MySql must fetch the whole page (block) of data, that contains several records. Using the sorted index, we must get records - one by one - from different places in the table, thus the same blocks of data are retrieved several times when we want to get 90% of the table using the index. In this case it's easier and cheapier to read them sequentially only once and sort them in the memory.